# loading big CSV file to SQLITE database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a very big CSV file (25 MB) with 90K lines and i am trying to make an Android app that will load this
What would be the most efficient way to load it to SQL db? Is that even possible? Any idea how long loading it will take?

Thank you

Comment: If you're looking for a way to ship data with you app you can include a prepopulated db in the apk, which is a much better experience for the users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database

Comment: Good idea but 2 problems with suggested solution. I read that asset folder can't have bigger than 1MG file. Also, I don't want to use the sqlite asset helper (not allowed to use outside libraries)

Comment: actually i checked and I can use it. if you put it as anaswer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to ship data with you app you can include a prepopulated db in the apk, which is a much better experience for the users: [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)